# Facebook URL by using php sdk is not loading

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I use the following code to connect to the facebook via my site, but the facebook page is not loading.
The cook is like that

```
    <?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '198516340340394',
  'secret' => 'f11117b96e0996ecbf7d7f4919c0cf70',
  'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = null;
if ($user) {

try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', array(
    'message' => 'I want to display this message on my wall'
));
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }

}

if ($user_profile) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  echo '<a href="$logoutUrl">Logout</a>';
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'publish_stream, read_friendlists',
  ));
  echo '<a href="$logoutUrl">Login</a>';
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHP SDK</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

and when I click on the login
[If you click on that login here it does not load the facebook](http://www.mrprofessional.se/ziaullah/)

what should I do in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting logoutUrl rather than loginUrl

Change:

```
echo '<a href="$logoutUrl">Login</a>';
```

to use

```
echo '<a href="'.$loginURL.'">Login</a>';
```

Comment: I did that but the same result, you can see on the link

Comment: You're setting the anchor as $loginUrl rather than dropping back to PHP in your echo to fill in the actual facebook URL. I've updated my answer above...

Comment: No problem - please accept the answer when ready so it can help anyone else browsing.